# Anonymous classes with lambdas in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to re-write my leisure time project from Java to Kotlin (to understand it) and I met some problems. Researches brought me to `{ function() }` but It didn't help me

In Java I have this interface:

```
public interface Shuffling<T> {

  List<T> shuffle(List<T> list, ShuffleCallback callback);

  interface ShuffleCallback {
    void onShuffle(int addedTo, int randomIndex);
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to add test object to List of shuffling algorithms in Kotlin:

```
val algoList = ArrayList<Shuffling<Int>>()
algoList.add(Shuffling { list, callback -> {
    Timber.d("Test!")
    ArrayList<Int>() // how to return this value?
}})
```

[image: First trouble]

How to add multiple lines to lambda function?

Also I have another example with troubles:

Kotlin interface:

```
interface Drawable {
    fun draw()
}
```

And Kotlin implementation:

```
private val drawList = ArrayList<Drawable>()

//...
drawList.add(Drawable {glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, startVertex, numVertices)})
```

[image: Second trouble]

Previously I used just:

```
mDrawList.add(() -> glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, startVertex, numVertices));
```

And everything was OK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, so here are the quick fixes:

For your first question: please remove the "internal" pair of brackets from your lambda. Now your code returns not `ArrayList<Int>()`, but a function that returns the list (when invoked)

For the second question: the trick that you used in your first question called SAM conversion and works *only* for java interfaces to be consistent with java8. Your `Drawable` is defined in Kotlin, so no black magic available, you have to create an instance and pass it:

```
drawList.add(object: Drawable {
    override fun draw() = glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, startVertex, numVertices)
})
```

for more info please read: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions

P.S you do not have to use `Shuffling` before a lambda. It is not needed here (I guess) and it complicates the the code a lot.

Comment: I tried to create lambda instance of shuffling, just to test how lambdas in kotlin work.

Comment: 1)  Am I able to add multi lines? Last line will return the value? But what if I use if/else? 
2) If I re-write interface to java's one, I'll be able to use lamdas? Or how to do this with Kotlin? I really like do not write this object, override, etc

Comment: would you prefer my incomplete, shortened answer or a link to docs?

Comment: heh, I think your answer would be more clear. Also yes, your solution works for me, but I still have that questions

Comment: And also, is it necessary to "cast" to Shuffling? Am I able somehow use just curly braces?

Comment: I don't really get your question about the lambda syntax but: (1) lines are not restricted, (2) the last expression in a lambda is returned (3) what is it so special about if\else?

Comment: about the interfaces: with Kotlin you can throw them out and use a functional type: `() -> Unit`. And I insist on you reading the docs, because it gets complicated here. Sorry :D https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types

Comment: Kinda this: http://pastie.org/10573950. And about interfaces, that was just because I wanted to create list of single method interface and put there kinda lambda from Java8

Comment: one question at a comment please! With the `if`: you got two options: (1) you add an `else` branch and put the `if` as the last expression https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression.

Or (2) if you feel geeky you may utilize a "function expression", cause it has returns and everything (but nobody like the syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you it would be good you to write object declaration before Shuffling declaration, because it is not declared by the system sometime. Then, inside shuffle method of Shuffle interface give a returnable value which is List.

**val algorist = ArrayList<Shuffling>()
algorist.add(object : Shuffling {
override fun shuffle(list: List, callback: Shuffling.ShuffleCallback): List {
println("Test")
return ArrayList()
}
})

```js
val algorist = ArrayList<Shuffling<Int>>()
algorist.add(object : Shuffling<Int> {
        override fun shuffle(list: List<Int>, callback: Shuffling.ShuffleCallback): List<Int> {
            println("Test")
            return ArrayList<Int>()
        }
    })
```

**

That is it. Happy coding...

Comment: Is it chatgpt generated?

Comment: Nope, that is my own writing. What did you ask for?

Comment: I am new here and have been in some problem to make answers that is it )